# Cocos 2d - launch image resizes from 568h to @2x on iPhone 5 automatically?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Hello! I am running the most basic Hello World app using Cocos2d, literally unmodified from the most basic cocos2d template in Xcode.

When I start the simulator the launch image for iPhone 5 automatically loads - however after a few seconds the launch image switches to the default@2x for iPhone 4, so there are two small back stripes of unused space on either side of the launch image.

Why is this so? And how can I make it so that the launch image doesn't automatically switch to smaller version for iPhone 4 after a few seconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In IntroLayer.mm add this code:

```
    CCSprite *background;
    if( IS_IPAD)
    {
         if(IS_RETINA)
            background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png"];
         else 
            background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default-Portrait~ipad.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        if(IS_IPHONE5)
            background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default-568h@2x.png"];
        else
        {
            if(IS_RETINA)
                background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default@2x.png"];
            else
                background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Default.png"];
        }
}
```

Used Macro:

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE5 (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_RETINA ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```